# Разные layout для приложения

Tags: android, android-layout

Есть планшеты 7':
1024x600
1920X1200

В разметке два ключевых вью:
снизу - AndroidSlidingUpPanel. Когда collapsed занимает 20%
сверху - Framelayout с фрагментом (список).

Не могу сделать ровный layout для каждого девайса, а именно значение высот вью.
Пробовал: sw, h классификаторы для layout.

Comment: глупый вопрос, но `weight` выставляли?

Comment: При запуске активности идентифицировать девайс из пула девайсов (3-5 разных девайсов / корпоративная разработка) и подсовывать соответстующий layout?

Comment: Да пробовал. SlidingUpPanel корневой вью, который должен иметь только 2 вложенных чайлда. Где верхний FrameL а нижний - LinearL.

Comment: а, у вас все в панели... когда-то тоже с ней мучался, Потом отказался. Вам обязательно реализацию делать через нее? Посмотрите, может такое https://github.com/AAkira/ExpandableLayout подойдет?